# manifest.webapp is not selectable on Firefox (Mac mini)

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I have Firefox OS 1.3 and Firefox OS 2.0 Simulator installed and I am trying to install a simple app on the Simulator, but somehow while installing the application I am not allowed to select the **manifest.webapp** file.

Check the image below

[image: Firefox about:app-manager: can’t select "manifest.webapp" in the file dialog]

As you can see the file selection is disabled!

I am using Firefox 33.0 and my system is Mac mini. I have tried it with other examples, too, but still I cannot select the **manifest.webapp** at all.

Is there somthing different on Mac systems? (I do not have a Windows system to try on)

Answer (score 2):

If your app is packaged app then it will not showing manifest.webapp file. Cause for packaged app you have to select whole project folder.
Other hand, for the hosted app you just provide the url location for manifest.webapp file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Mac problem. All you need to do is to press **"OPEN"** and it will automatically import your project to App Manager.

Please take note that you can also download Firefox Developer Edition and take advantage of WebIDE. It's like App Manager but even better.

More here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/11/mozilla-introduces-the-first-browser-built-for-developers-firefox-developer-edition/